# Update page section after dropdown selection multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select dropdown menu with shipping options. I'd like the target ID to update after a shipping option is selected as many times as the user changes options. Currently the option will only update once.

Variable tags using {} are from ExpressionEngine, but I'm not sure this situation is particular to EE.

Code as follows:

HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span>Shipping:</span>
            <select name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method">
                <option value="">Select shipping method...</option>
                {shipping_method_options}
            </select>
        </th>
        <th id="js-shipping-price">
            {order_shipping}
        </th>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
   $('#shipping_method').change(function() {
        var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
        var data = $(this.form).serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function() {
            $('#js-shipping-price').load('/global/shipping-price');
        });
        return false;
    });
```

As I'm not well-versed in jQuery, the above code is mostly from: [How to implement AJAX “add to cart” with Expresso Store?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5978/how-to-implement-ajax-add-to-cart-with-expresso-store/)

Tried removing `return: false;` since I'm not sure it's needed in this case (I'm not sure though), but same results.

EDIT:

`/global/shipping-price` is an EE variable tag used to return the shipping value of the option selected:

```
{exp:store:checkout}{order_shipping}{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: It looks like you're loading the same thing every time. What does `/global/shipping-price` return that varies?

Comment: Ah thanks, forgot to explain that. `/global/shipping-price` returns a variable of the selected shipping price. EE variable in this case but I think could be PHP also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using event delegation to make sure the new data is being used:

```
$(document).on('change', '#shipping_method', function() {
    ...
});
```